How do I access any directory and file in shared storage on newer Androids?
I'm developing a file manager, and it works fine with Android 12 when I ask for permissions
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />.
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />.

But it does not work for Android 13 (permission window does not appear). Code I'm using to get list of files and directories
val files = File(path).directory.listFiles()

So I tried using
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />.

And still I cannot request it (request doesn't appear). I tried searching and found out that I should use the Storage Access Framework (SAF), but the docs say that I can no longer access:

The root directory
The download directory.

As it's quite important to have access to these directories, I need help finding out how to access these shared directories and their files (and, if possible, a way to do this for newer and older versions of Android).

You can register for the MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. This requires the user to manually grant the permission to you via the Settings app. It also will require additional documentation for the Play Store (and possibly other app distribution channels) — they will not distribute apps requesting that permission unless there is a clear justification for it.

Look this
Declare the MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in the manifest.
You need open to "setting" by Context.startActivty()
params : Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION)

also: Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION,Uri.parse(package:packageName)),but i can't success.
If you succeed, please let me know


This code must be used after API 30

